# Is there anyway we can calculate this integral $\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(y)e^{\frac{1}{(x-y)^2-1}} \,dy.$ what I want is an explicit function of $x$.

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, convolution

Is there anyway we can calculate this integral $\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(y)e^{\frac{1}{(x-y)^2-1}} \,dy.$ what I want is an explicit function of $x$.

here $f(y)$ is a piecewise continuous function.

$f(y)=1$ when $y\geq0$

$f(y)=0$ when $y<0$

I tried the following,

Set $u=x-y$ then the integral transformed to the following.

$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.$=$\int_{-1}^{x} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du + \int_{x}^{1} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.$

since $f(x-u)=0$ when $u>x$,

we have the following.
$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.$=$\int_{-1}^{x} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.$

$\int_{-1}^{x} f(x-u)e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.=\int_{-1}^{x}e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du.$

Are theses steps valid so far? How do I continue from here.

What I know is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{1}{u^2-1}} \,du=1$.

Comment: That last sentence is definitely not true. Have you looked at a plot of the function?